# Send quantity of product from form to shopping cart

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing a form where the difference of two dates is calculated. I need this difference to be added to the shopping cart as the product quantity with id = '18 '.

[image]
***In the image, the difference between the two dates is 23 days.***

The plugin that I use to make the form in Wordpress allows me to assign the OnClick event to the button.

[image]

As you realize in the image, I have put:

> window.location="http://localhost/travelagent/?add-to-cart=18";

This line of code what it does is add me the product but only once, what I want is that it be added according to the amount calculated previously. In this example it would be 23.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the quantity param like this:

```
window.location="http://localhost/travelagent/?add-to-cart=18&quantity=23";
```

Comment: Thank you! It was so simple! And if I want you to also show me the screen: http://localhost/travelagent/cart/. What else would be added?

Comment: Sorry @JuanSánchez, I don't get what you mean. And don't share localhost link, it will only work on your computer...

Comment: Of course, I know, what I want is that after pressing the button and adding the amount to the shopping cart, take me to the shopping cart screen (www.myweb.com/cart/), since the url where I sent the quantity only it adds it but it takes me to the main screen or index.

Answer (score 0):

as answered by Reigel:

http://localhost/travelagent/?add-to-cart=18&quantity=23

To redirect to the cart automatically you need to change the setting on the WooCommerce Settings page -> Products -> Redirect to cart (checkbox).